# How to create a new column with counts of how many times a variable value appears in a column in R

Tags: r

I am very new to R, and I am struggling with trying to create a new variable for use with RFM.

I have customer ID per purchase, some of the ID's appear repeatedly, some only once.

I figured that if I were to measure the number of times each ID repeats - for example ID 1 appears 3 times - then I will know that this specific customer's frequency is 3. There are 500 customers, but over 1700 replies.

Comment: Every time you post, it would be helpful (and appreciated) to use a reproducible example and to clarify which output you are expecting. See https://community.rstudio.com/t/faq-how-to-do-a-minimal-reproducible-example-reprex-for-beginners/23061

Comment: Ah, thank you Emy, I will so in the future :)

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to create a new variable, so I decided upon creating a new value using

```
frq = table(df$consumer_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `plyr` for this case:

```
library(plyr)
df <- ddply(df, .("Customer_ID"), transform, Customer_Frequency = count("Customer_ID"))
```